# SharePoint 2010 Filter Web Parts

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I cannot seem to get the SharePoint 2010 Filter Web Parts to display.  I tried enabling the SharePoint Server Enterprise Web application features at the Site Collection level (Central Admin - Manage Web Applications - Select Web Application - Manage Features - SharePoint Server Enterprise Web application features - Activate) as well as at the Site level (Site Actions - Site Settings - Manage site features - SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features - Activate), but they still don't show up when I browse the list of web parts in the Filter Category.

I think I'm enabling the correct feature sets.  Is there another dependency or something else I'm missing?

Additional note: I'm getting around this issue by manually adding the web parts to the Web Part Gallery for my site.  It's a bit of a nuisance, but I am moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features.

Answer (score 0):

This is a SharePoint 2010 Server.  I located the following six filters on the SharePoint server in c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Share\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\BizAppsSiteTemplates:

- BusinessDataFilter.dwp
- DateFilter.dwp
- FilterActions.dwp
- OlapFilter.dwp
- SpListFilter.dwp
- TextFilter.dwp

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is a known bug: [kb2623582](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2623582)