# Sharepoint 2010. Web part filter category is missed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have to use standard Sharepoint 2010 filters for my list view as described in this article:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20882.sharepoint-2010-tips-on-implementing-the-sharepoint-filter-list-web-part.aspx

but *filter category* mentioned here:

[image: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-wikis-components-files/00-00-00-00-05/7484.FilterTips.01.png]

is missed for my site :(

I have created site based on "Records Centre" template (template that should have most of features installed out-of-the-box) but no luck.

My Sharepoint DB version is: 14.0.4762.1000

Centeral administration tells me that it is: *Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010*
And when I go to "Migration" option it tells me that I have "Standard CAL" license

Do filters require enterprise license for Sharepoint 2010 server ?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated license to Enterprise and filters have appeared in web-parts categories.

Now I wonder if I could use them with Standard license

Alike question: [SharePoint 2010 Filter Web Parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458913/sharepoint-2010-filter-web-parts)